# rospkg.manifest.InvalidManifest

Tags: ros-fuerte, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I run roscore,the output is like below,how can I solve this problem?

```
WARNING: unable to configure logging. No log files will be generated
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rosversion", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('rospkg==1.0.2', 'rosversion')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 499, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1235, in run_script
    execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosversion", line 76, in <module>
    version = rosstack.get_stack_version(stack_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/rospkg/rospack.py", line 359, in get_stack_version
    return get_stack_version_by_dir(self.get_path(stack))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/rospkg/rospack.py", line 412, in get_stack_version_by_dir
    m = parse_manifest_file(stack_dir, STACK_FILE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/rospkg/manifest.py", line 343, in parse_manifest_file
    return parse_manifest(manifest_name, f.read(), filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/rospkg/manifest.py", line 404, in parse_manifest
    m.author = _check('author')(p, filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/rospkg/manifest.py", line 67, in check
    raise InvalidManifest("Invalid manifest file [%s]: must have a single '%s' element"%(filename, name))
rospkg.manifest.InvalidManifest: Invalid manifest file [/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/stack.xml]: must have a single 'author' element
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [rosversion]: command [rosversion ros] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="rosversion ros" name="rosversion"/>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207802/rospkg.manifest.invalidmanifest/) by [sunny2015](https://answers.ros.org/users/22258/sunny2015/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-04-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2015-04-24**:
some more or better info, what commands did you run to install? what os, which ros version, etc, etc,

**Comment by [sunny2015](https://answers.ros.org/users/22258/sunny2015/) on 2015-04-24**:
Fuerte and Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise)

**Comment by [sunny2015](https://answers.ros.org/users/22258/sunny2015/) on 2015-04-24**:
I run : sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full to install fuerte

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2015-04-24**:
sorry, dont know, try to remove and re-install again

**Comment by [sunny2015](https://answers.ros.org/users/22258/sunny2015/) on 2015-04-24**:
how to remove the ros? sorry, I am a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are running a very old version of rospkg. The last verion released is 1.0.35 your traceback indicates 1.0.2 which was released in April 2012.

Also from your trackback I can see it's located in /usr/local/lib which is indicative of a pip/easy_install based installation. You should make sure to uninstall that copy which will mask out the newer version from the debian packages. To see how to uninstall via pip you can get instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173323/how-do-i-detect-and-remove-python-packages-installed-via-pip/259747#259747)

To see what version you're running check that you get something like the following.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep rospkg
ii  python-rospkg                                         1.0.35-1                                            all          ROS package library
$ pip freeze | grep rospkg
rospkg==1.0.35
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0